# Inserting zoomed-in plot with full scale plot in sp package in R

Tags: r, zoom, sp, plot

I am using the `sp` package in `R` to plot sampled points along a river. However, I would like to zoom in to a sampled area of the entire river, and plot this zoomed area on the full length of the river. Using the `spplot` function is useful, as I have various variables per point. To "zoom" in, I can simple change the `ylim` and `xlim` arguments when using the `spplot` function.

Using the `meuse` dataset as an example

```
library(sp)
library(lattice) 
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)=~x+y 
FUll.study<-spplot(meuse)            #Gives the full study area
ZOOM<-spplot(meuse, xlim=c(170000,  181000), ylim=c(329714,333611))   #Random area to zoom in.
```

The results look like this:

[image]

However the desired result is something like this:

[image]
I am trying to find a way to add the `ZOOM` to an area on the `Full.study` map.I suspect because `spplot` is dependent on `lattice` it may not be possible. In that case, I would have to create a map for each variable independently, and add the respective zoomed area, probably through `par(new=TRUE)`, but this is just a thought. I would still have to figure out how to specify the location and adjust the size of the of zoomed area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using [ggplot](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2). I use `ggplotGrob` to combine the full and zoomed map and `grid.arrange` from the [gridExtra](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gridExtra) add-on to combine the maps for different variables. There are many adjustments that can be made, of course.

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid) # for unit
library(gridExtra) # for grid.arrange

# zoom bounding box
xlim <- c(179500,181000); ylim <- c(332000,332500)

# size of zoomed area - offset from top left corner of main plot: 
x_offs <- 1000 ; y_offs <- 1300

# settings for full plot
fulltheme <- theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            panel.background = element_blank(), 
            axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks=element_blank(),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())

# settings for zoom plot
zoomtheme <- theme(legend.position="none", axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            panel.background = element_rect(color='red', fill="white"),
            plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,-6,-6),"mm"))


############## point example  #############
data(meuse)

# variables to plot
vars <- names(meuse)[3:10]

plotlist <- list()

for (i in vars) {
  # full plot
  p.full <- ggplot(meuse, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", color=i)) + 
    geom_point() + fulltheme
  # zoomed plot
  p.zoom <- ggplot(meuse, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", color=i)) + 
    geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim) + zoomtheme
  # put them together
  g <- ggplotGrob(p.zoom)
  plotlist[[length(plotlist) + 1]] <- p.full + 
    annotation_custom(grob = g, xmin = min(meuse$x), xmax = min(meuse$x) + x_offs, ymin = max(meuse$y) - y_offs, ymax = max(meuse$y))
}

# plot
do.call(grid.arrange,  c(plotlist, ncol=4))
```

[image]

Similarly, [ggplot](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2) can handle rasters.

```
############################################
############## raster example  #############

library(raster)

r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
s <- stack(r, r*2, log(r))
names(s) <- c('meuse', 'meuse2', 'meuseLog')
meuseRast <- data.frame(rasterToPoints(s))

rastvars <- names(meuseRast)[-c(1:2)]
plotrast <- list()

for (i in rastvars) {
   p.fullrast <- ggplot(meuseRast, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", fill = i)) + 
      geom_raster() + fulltheme

   p.zoomrast <- ggplot(meuseRast, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", fill = i)) + 
      geom_raster() + coord_cartesian(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim) + zoomtheme

   g <- ggplotGrob(p.zoomrast)
   plotrast[[length(plotrast) + 1]] <- p.fullrast + 
     annotation_custom(grob = g, xmin = min(meuseRast$x), xmax = min(meuseRast$x) + x_offs, ymin = max(meuseRast$y) - y_offs, ymax = max(meuseRast$y))
}

# plot
do.call(grid.arrange,  c(plotrast, nrow=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `maptools::elide` function to translate coordinates of a `Spatial*`object. If you combine the result with the `sp.layout` argument of `spplot` or with the `latticeExtra::layer` function, you will get what you need:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)=~x+y 

ZOOM <- crop(meuse, extent(180000,  181000, 330000, 331500))

displaced <- elide(ZOOM, shift = c(-1200, 2000))

spplot(meuse["zinc"], scales = list(draw = TRUE)) +
    layer({
        sp.points(ZOOM, col = 'black')
        sp.points(displaced, col = '')
    })
```

[image: elide]